# Bing search API - How to localize results?

Tags: bing, bing-api

How can I use Slovenian search results by default? Our server has German IP and Bing API automatically shows German results first. I have already tried some of the parameters as described in documentation and none of them worked so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set the Market option?

According to [this example page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250861.aspx), you should try something like this (note `&Market=sl-SL` argument):

```
http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId=your_AppId&Query=your_query&Sources=Web&Version=2.0&Market=sl-SL&Options=EnableHighlighting&Web.Count=10&Web.Offset=0&JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=SearchCompleted
```

Comment: Could you please tell me that where can I get valid values for **Market** parameter?

Answer (score 2):

> **First off, Slovenia is currently not a Bing Market or Country.**

There are 2 mutually exclusive options to configure a localization.
*Since Slovenia is not yet supported, you might want to use 2. to combine results from relevant markets.*

- Using *mkt* and *setLang*

The values for *mkt* - Market Code are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v5-reference#market-codes).

The **query** value *setLang*, "The language to use for user interface strings. Specify the language using the [ISO 639-1 2-letter language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). For example, the language code for English is EN. The default is EN (English)."

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=microsoft&mkt=en-US&setLang=EN
```

- Using *cc* and *Accept-Language*

The values for *cc* - Country Code are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v5-reference#countrycodes).

This allows you to specify multiple languages via the **header** value *[Accept-Language](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)*.

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=microsoft&cc=US
```

> True, setting the Accept-Language does very little for the actual
>   result. If you want to localize outside of a Bing market country, you'll like have to include a translation service.

Answer (score 1):

[Values for the Market parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251064.aspx)