# Bing Search with market return strange result

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have a strange behaviour with Bing Web Search.

I have a search query `"hawkers" OR "hawkersco" OR "@hawkersco" OR "#hawkers" OR "www.hawkersco.com"` with market = 'es-ES', safeSearch = Strict and responseFilter = webPages.

So, I expect, that result will contain at least one of these words and it will be Spanish posts. In fact I get more of posts in English and its not contain these keywords...

If I try search one by one these keywords, without OR operator, I had expected Spanish posts.

Please, explain why it is? How to use search query for get expected results?..

Answer (score 0):

Check the specification for [Bing Web Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v5-reference#mkt). Possibly this might be as simple as changing *market* to *mkt*(since you listed all the other parameters as used). And that means you should have a value for *setLang* as well.

You're not getting Spanish posts at all?

In that case, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565044/7152407).

> Bing results are based on relevance. Regardless of Market or Language.
>   If the result is deemed relevant. It will rank higher compared to the
>   selected language, and appear in the results.
>
> Freshness affects the results, in that you need relevant(popular)
>   sites in your language. For them to attain sufficient relevance in the
>   selected time period.
>
> You cannot rely on Bing returning a single language exclusively, with
>   the settings as they are.

Comment: It was my mistake, that wrote _market_ in the question. Exactly, I used _mkt_. By the way, _setLang_ not helped me.
Another query: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=%22orsay%22&count=50&safesearch=Strict&freshness=Day&mkt=es-ES&responseFilter=Webpages&setLang=ES&offset=0
It have not even one Spanish post. Only English, French, German... Is it normal for Bing?..

Comment: Bit more detail on localization options added.
I get some Spanish results if I use the mkt=es-ES and setLang = es options. Also with cc=ES and Accept-Language=ES.

Comment: Trying _cc_ and _Accept-Language_. Result is same. My problem still exist.

Comment: Using this?
search?q="hawkers"OR"hawkersco"OR"@hawkersco"OR"#hawkers"OR"www.hawkersco.com"&mkt=es-ES

Comment: This [one](https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q="hawkers"OR"hawkersco"OR"@hawkersco"OR"#hawkers"OR"‌​www.hawkersco.com"&m‌​kt=es-ES&count=50&safesearch=Strict&freshness=Day&responseFilter=Webpages&offset=0&cc=ES&setLang=ES) have 10 posts, only one with Spanish snippet.
This [one](https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q="orsay"&m‌​kt=es-ES&count=50&safesearch=Strict&freshness=Day&responseFilter=Webpages&offset=0&cc=ES&setLang=ES) have 21 posts, no one Spanish. 17 - English, 2 Italian and 2 French.

Comment: You realize that &freshness=Day requires new Spanish articles to be indexed and ranked sufficiently high for them to show? If you try without, top is Spanish.
Also you might consider cleaning up the query string a bit.

Comment: 1) I just want that if I specify _mkt_ or _setLang_ = _es-ES_ or _ES_, then I will get Spanish posts, not Italian, not other languages. If Bing have not Spanish posts, then I expect, that response will be empty.
2) If _freshness=Day_ not work right, so why it exist? I need this filter, so why I have remove it? Just because it not work?..

Comment: So, please, what the solution are you offer? How I understand, if Bing have not reliable result, it will give anything, that more or less contain something from request? And what about _freshness=Day_ I cannot use it?

Comment: Bing results are based on relevance. If the result is deemed still more relevant to your market and language. It will rank higher. Freshness affects the results in that you need popular sites in your language. For them to attain sufficient relevance in the selected time period. You cannot rely on Bing returning a single language exclusively, with the settings as they are.