# Bing News Search API language translation of results?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-news-search-api

I am querying Bing News Search for foreign markets like China, Malaysia, Russia etc. The results are not always in English. Is there a way or a parameter I can set which would translate all results to English?

Or would I have to do this separately from the Bing News Search API by calling a different language translation API? The setLang parameter doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation, `setLang` should not be used to set the language of search results. I checked the official documents. In 2012, Microsoft recommended using [`JSON Code Sample (Web SourceType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/search/dd251093(v=msdn.10)). I tested it and it didn't take effect. You can view related posts.

[**Bing search API - How to localize results?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677824/bing-search-api-how-to-localize-results)

Because the existing materials are too old, they are all documents many years ago. So I recommend using Microsoft's [`Translator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/translatortext/translator/transliterate#transliteratetextinput).

Below I provide sample code, replacing the values of `OcpApimSubscriptionKey1` and `OcpApimSubscriptionKey1` and `OcpApimSubscriptionRegion`, which can be run directly. The effect diagram is as follows.

***Note:***

*1. The sample code provided is only a reference code, and it needs to take into account the processing of special characters when used in a production environment.*

*2. Sample code The non-optimal sample code is just my sample.*

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Translate</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var OcpApimSubscriptionKey1="267****6fac1978";
        var OcpApimSubscriptionKey2="00d****bff196393";
        var OcpApimSubscriptionRegion="koreacentral";
        var tmp_jsonstr="";
        $(document).ready(function(){

        })
        function bingnewssearch(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://panshubeicognitiveservices.cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0/news/search?q='+$("#keywords").val()+"&mkt=zh-CN&setLang=EN&cc=EN&count=5",
                method: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=urf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', OcpApimSubscriptionKey1);
                },
                success:function(result){
                    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(result);
                    tmp_jsonstr=myJSON;
                    $("#orginresult").html(myJSON)
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("Oop, No Data Response");
                }
            })
        }
        function translatejson(){
            var str="[{\"Text\":\""+tmp_jsonstr.replace(/\"/g,"'")+"'\"}]";
            
            var jsonData=eval( str);//JSON.parse(str);
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=zh-Hans&to=en",
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data:str,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', OcpApimSubscriptionKey2);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region', OcpApimSubscriptionRegion);
                },
                success:function(result){
                    var myJSON1 = JSON.stringify(result);
                    var str=result[0].translations[0].text;
                    str="{"+str.replace(/'/g, '"')+"}"
                    $("#translatedresult").html(str)
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("Oop, No Data Response");
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div><p>Bing News Search</p></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="keywords" placeholder="key words"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="bingnewssearch()">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div>Orgin Result</div>
        <div>
            <span id="orginresult"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="translatejson()">translate orgindata</button>
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <span id="translatedresult"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```